# How to resolve maven expression in source code in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm usin templating-maven-plugin to in order to filter main sources, so it injects some value directly in java code while project building. And it works well while I'm using only maven but when it comes to run the project in InteillIj it doesn't resolve meven exporession in the code like "${someParam}";

*Using properties file it isn't a solution for me*

Example

```
public class TestObject {
    String surname = "${someParam}";

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("My name is " + surname);
    }
}

POM CONFIG
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>filter-src</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>filter-sources</goal><!--filter main sources -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

So when I do **mvn clean install -DsomeParam=TEST** it works well but when I run it in intellij even with run config -DsomeParam=TEST it prints My name is ${someParam}

Comment: does your run config even run the maven steps?

Comment: I've tried maven run config it work better but I can not run project in debug mode for that I have to add a remote debug config so it is a lot of config to add, is there a way to do it with only one run config?

Comment: If you are creating source code you should use the generate-sources phase instead ...